# What's the logic behind Zelda's Octoball minigame?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I'm trying to get the 100 Rupees from the Octoball minigame in Link Between Worlds.

What ***is*** the logic in this minigame? How is one *supposed* to play this? All you are told is that you can change the stance by moving up and down the joystick, which seems to modify the distance the ball is thrown. However, how does one control the horizontal direction? It is seemingly random to me.

I know that I should be hitting pots consecutively so the bird appears and I can get its 20 Rupees. However, all my shots seem to be random!

I am literally hitting the ball without the faintest idea what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The baseball minigame is actually fairly easy once you understand how it works.

The ball's direction depends on when you hit it.
Hit it early, and it'll fly in the direction you're swinging (if I'm not mistaken, that should be the left); hit it late and it'll fly in the other direction.

In the end, it all comes down to timing.

Comment: It should also be noted that shifting your stance with the joystick doesn't affect how far the ball goes but does affect how high it travels when it's first hit. Tilt it all the way forward for a ground-roll, useful for hitting the closest pots on the ground, or tilt all the way back to 'aim for the fence' and hit the pots on top of the trees.

Answer (score 1):

You can **control the ball’s left-right angle with the timing** of when you hit the ball. An **earlier** hit causes the ball to fly more to the **right**. If you hit the ball when it is in front of the home plate, it will fly right, if you hit the ball when it is over the home plate, it will fly straight ahead, and if you hit the ball later, it will fly to the left.

You can change stance by moving the analog pad up or down. Only three stances are useful: neutral to hit the back line of pots or the crow, holding all the way down to hit the far-back and elevated pots, and holding all the way up to hit the pots closer on the ground or the crabs.

The key to getting rupees is summoning the crow with a three-pot chain, then hitting it reliably. You can make it easier to hit three pots consecutively by aiming for different distances on three hits. For example, hit a low hit on your first shot, then a medium hit, then a high hit. This way, you have to worry less about hitting the ball in the exact same direction and having your ball just roll through where a pot used to be.

When the crow appears, it will always be at the medium distance, and almost always be a little to the right of the pitcher Otto. If you can memorize the timing to hit in that direction, you will hit the crow consistently.

As well hitting pots consistently by aiming for different distances, try to aim for the golden pot. Aiming for a golden pot may be too risky if you have already hit the pots to the sides of that pot.

If too many pots are gone, try to hit the ground pots near crabs. But try not to hit those pots early in the game – save those pots for later. That way, if you try to hit a crab and miss, you will still hit a pot and keep up your chain. If you happen to hit a crab, not only will pots be restored, making it easier to keep up a three-pot chain, but you won’t even break your current chain.